# Публикация записи без согласия

Tags: post, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Как можно реализовать публикацию записи на стену группы, если я являюсь владельцем группы без согласия на размещения, т.е без постоянного подтверждения?

Вообще это возможно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого Вам необходимо:

1. зарегистрировать Standalone-приложение
2. получить токен с правами доступа к стене (`scope=wall`).

После чего у Вас появится доступ к методам Wall, включая `Wall.post`.

https://vk.com/editapp?act=create
https://vk.com/dev/wall